# what is the problem in this sql statement?

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I write this statement which works correctly in all cases except one case

```
SELECT p.priv_no FROM osqs_privileges p,osqs_users_privileges up 
WHERE up.priv_no = p.priv_no AND up.user_no = 54 AND up."GRANT" = 'Y' 
    UNION 
SELECT p.priv_no FROM 
osqs_privileges p,osqs_groups_privileges gp,osqs_users_groups ug,osqs_users_privileges up 
    WHERE gp.priv_no = p.priv_no AND ug.grp_no = gp.grp_no AND ug.user_no = 54 
AND gp.priv_no NOT IN 
    (SELECT priv_no FROM osqs_users_privileges WHERE user_no = 54 AND "GRANT" = 'N');
```

in a case that osqs_users_privileges have no rows  and this statement (SELECT priv_no FROM osqs_users_privileges WHERE user_no = 54 AND "GRANT" = 'N') return 0 rows, all the script return 0 rows even if othe select statements returns data. why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use an OUTER JOIN:

```
SELECT p.priv_no FROM osqs_privileges p,osqs_users_privileges up 
WHERE up.priv_no = p.priv_no AND up.user_no = 54 AND up."GRANT" = 'Y' 
    UNION 
SELECT p.priv_no 
FROM osqs_privileges p
LEFT JOIN osqs_groups_privileges gp on osqs_users_groups ug on gp.priv_no = p.priv_no
LEFT JOIN osqs_users_privileges up on ug.grp_no = gp.grp_no
WHERE ug.user_no = 54 
AND gp.priv_no NOT IN 
    (SELECT priv_no FROM osqs_users_privileges WHERE user_no = 54 AND "GRANT" = 'N');
```

Comment: ,,
it gives an error: invalid relational operator in this line
LEFT JOIN osqs_groups_privileges gp on osqs_users_groups ug on gp.priv_no = p.priv_no

Comment: thank you very much , you give me the way.
 but I altered your answer

Answer (score 5):

It's due to the behaviour of NULLs in the NOT IN clause.

For example,

```
select 'yes' where 3 in (1, 2, 3, null)  -- Return result
select 'yes' where 3 not in (1, 2, null) -- Returns an empty set
```

Why? Because `3 <> null` results in `UNKNOWN`.

> **Nulls in Conditions**
>
> A condition that evaluates to UNKNOWN acts almost like FALSE. For
>   example, a SELECT statement with a condition in the WHERE clause that
>   evaluates to UNKNOWN returns no rows. However, a condition evaluating
>   to UNKNOWN differs from FALSE in that further operations on an UNKNOWN
>   condition evaluation will evaluate to UNKNOWN. Thus, NOT FALSE
>   evaluates to TRUE, but NOT UNKNOWN evaluates to UNKNOWN.

[Ref](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements005.htm).

Answer (score 0):

this is the right command:

```
    SELECT p.priv_no FROM osqs_privileges p,osqs_users_privileges up 
WHERE up.priv_no = p.priv_no AND up.user_no = 55 AND up."GRANT" = 'Y' 
    UNION 
SELECT p.priv_no 
FROM osqs_privileges p 
LEFT JOIN osqs_groups_privileges gp on gp.priv_no = p.priv_no 
LEFT JOIN osqs_users_groups ug on ug.grp_no = gp.grp_no 
LEFT JOIN osqs_users_privileges up on up.priv_no = p.priv_no 
WHERE ug.user_no = 55 
AND gp.priv_no NOT IN 
    (SELECT priv_no FROM osqs_users_privileges WHERE user_no = 55 AND "GRANT" = 'N') ;
```